# How to do Perl regex with alternation and substitution

Tags: regex, perl, alternation

I wish to transform "eAlpha eBeta eGamma" into "fAlpha fBeta fGamma."  Of course this is just a simplified example of more complex substitutions.

Here is my perl program:

```
my $data= "eAlpha eBeta eGamma";
$data=~ s/(e)(Alpha)|(e)(Beta)|(e)(Gamma)/f$2/g;
say $data;
```

The output is

```
fAlpha f f
```

Perl regex seems to remember the $1 but not the $2.  Is there a way to use regex alternation, global substitution, and capture variables like $1, $2?

- There are  never more than 3 alternates so I could do it in three steps but wish not to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use look ahead?

Comment: I'd use `s/e(Alpha|Beta|Gamma)/f$1/g;`

Answer (score 1):

You an use positive look ahead using alternation and just match `e` and substitute it with `f`.

```
my $data = "eAlpha eBeta eGamma";
$data=~ s/e(?=Alpha|Beta|Gamma)/f/g;
print($data);
```

Prints,

```
fAlpha fBeta fGamma
```

Answer (score 0):

The capture groups go from left to right without "respecting" the `|`. So `Beta` gets captured in `$4` and `Gamma` in `$6`.

But you can condense it to two groups and additionally make the first group non-capturing with `?:` (or don't use a group at all, as it's just a single character, but you may have something else in there in the "real thing" that requires a group).

```
...
$data =~ s/(?:e)(Alpha|Beta|Gamma)/f$1/g;
...
```

Comment: This works as well, sticky bit.  Using your explanation how the capture groups go, I found out that s/(e)(Alpha)|(e)(Beta)|(e)(Gamma)/f$2$4$6/g Also works!

Comment: `(?:e)(Alpha|Beta|Gamma)` is a weird way of writing `e(Alpha|Beta|Gamma)`

Comment: @Cab, Re "*s/(e)(Alpha)|(e)(Beta)|(e)(Gamma)/f$2$4$6/g Also works!*", Yes, but it's wasteful and overly complex. In short, bad code.

Comment: @ikegami: Notice the text in parenthesis in my post. I used a group to show them, that these can be made non capturing if in the real, not simplified code they use, they really need a group for some reason. But I also pointed out, that they don't need any group for just a single character.